# Get some values from each object in Scala List of objects and send it to HTTP

Tags: json, mongodb, scala, playframework

I'm newbie in scala and play framework.I have a list of JSon objects, I'm trying  to retrieve only two attributes (name and image) of each object in the list and send it in Json format to http response, I'm using mongoDB to get the full list

```
def NamesImages = Action.async {implicit request =>
val FutureProducts = productDao.find(BSONDocument()).collect[List]()
FutureProducts.map { prod => prod.map {
        a => 
        val prdObj = Json.obj("name" -> JsObject(a.name.get), "image" -> JsObject(a.image))
            Ok(new JsArray(Json.toJson(prdObj)))
        }
}}
```

I got compilation error:

```
 **type mismatch;**

 found   : play.api.libs.json.JsValue
 required: Seq[play.api.libs.json.JsValue]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to Wrap your result with a Seq. JsArray want a sequence of JsValue
Try this:

```
    def NamesImages = Action.async {implicit request =>
val FutureProducts = productDao.find(BSONDocument()).collect[List]()
FutureProducts.map { prod => Ok(JsArray(prod.map {
        a => Json.obj("name" -> JsObject(a.name.get), "image" -> JsObject(a.image))
            }))
}}
```

Comment: I got another error :
type mismatch;
 found   : List[play.api.mvc.Result]
 required: play.api.mvc.Result

Comment: Ah sure, I didn't see that you are returning the result inside the map function. I edit the answear

Comment: It works now.. Thank You, can you give some explanation please

Comment: Sure. In Play Framework each Action must return just one Result ( Result is the http response ), or in case you are using actions.async you have to return a Future[Result]. JsArray now is initialized with a List of JsValue that comes form the map operation.